# Combine 2 Columns in One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, select-query

hi I have two separate columns [StuName , StuLName]

in select i use like this :

`Select StuName, StuLName From Tbl_Student`

> Result : [Mahdi], [Hosseini]

is there any way to combine this 2 columns in one column (only in select) something like this :

`Select StuName + " " + StuLName From Tbl_Student`

Result (for example) :

> Mahdi Hosseini

StuName and StuLName are NVARCHAR

Comment: The way you have it should work. Have you tried?

Comment: might need to use ' rather than "

Comment: yes i tried but not work, its return null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query ought to work. Otherwise, you can also use `[CONCAT]` to string togehter two or more strings:

```
SELECT CONCAT('First' , ' ' , 'Last' )
```

Result:

```
First Last
```

More info about Concat on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql).

In your case, this ought to do the trick:

```
SELECT CONCAT(StuName, ' ',StuLName) AS StudentName FROM Tbl_Student
```

Comment: you can add example with OP's columns and table name, that would be more useful to him/her.

Comment: @Nino - Done :) Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Chapache01 You're most welcome. If this solved your problem, please remember to mark it as the answer, so future visitors of the question can easily find the resolution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME AS ColumnZ 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses a pair of single quote instead of double quote. This should worked fine:

```
Select StuName + ' ' + StuLName From Tbl_Student
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query, one of the column might have null value so it will return a null value

```
 Select ISNULL(StuName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(StuLName,'') From Tbl_Student
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your statement tries to get a column named " ". If you only want a space character you need to use single quotation: ' '. With double quotation you refer to a column or a database object in general.

SqlServers string concatenation returns null if at least one of the concatenated values is null:

```
'te' + 'st' = 'test'
```

but

```
'te' + null = null
```

To ensure you get a value, you have to ensure, that all parts deliver a non null value. This is done using **isNull** or **coalesce**. I prefer **coalesce** because it is imho more of a standard (correct me if I am wrong). Or you could use the very useful **concat** function, that takes care of all this for its parameters.

So your statement should look like this:

```
Select coalesce(StuName,'') + ' ' + coalesce(StuLName,'') From Tbl_Student
```

or

```
Select concat(StuName,' ',StuLName) From Tbl_Student
```